# Error from Updater Application Cron Script

Tags: magento2, cron, file-permissions

Error from Updater Application Cron Script
Found non-writable path(s):
/home/USERNAME/public_html/.htaccess.sample

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's just a permission problem.

Just make this `.htaccess.sample` writeable for the user that runs the script

You can find the permissions documentation on the official website: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Yes. But I actually dont have this file in the directory! .htaccess.sample! So weird

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with that .htaccess.sample.

And I thought it was a permission problem but it was not so what I did is I created that .htaccess.sample file and I run my cron using this commands "bin/magento cron:run" then "bin/magento indexer:reindex" and it solves my problem.

I hope this would help